# Invalid package provider 'pear'

Tags: php, puppet, pear

I'm creating a manifest to install LAMP on a CentOS 6 machine.  Everything works except for installing some pear modules.  When issuing `puppet /etc/puppet/modules/webserver/manifests/init.pp` I get the following:

> Invalid package provider 'pear' at
>   /etc/puppet/modules/webserver/manifests/init.pp:111

Here are the relevant parts of the manifest, including the order of includes at the bottom:

```
class php {

  package {'php':
    ensure => present,  
    before => File['/etc/php.ini'],
  }

  file {'/etc/php.ini':
    ensure => file,
  }

  $packagelist = [
    "php-cli",
    "php-common",
    "php-devel",
    "php-gd",
    "php-ldap",
    "php-mbstring",
    "php-mssql",
    "php-mysql",
    "php-pear",
    "php-pecl-ssh2",
    "php-xml"
  ]

  package { $packagelist:
    ensure => installed,
    require => Package['php'],
    notify => Service['httpd'],
  }

class pear {
  package {
     "pear":
        ensure => installed,
        provider => 'pear';
     "pecl/zip":
        ensure => installed,
        provider => 'pear';
  }
}

include php
include pear
```

I can comment out the `include pear` line at the bottom, and the rest installs without a hitch.  `rpm -qa | grep php-pear` shows that package php-pear was successfully installed.  Issuing `pear` at a prompt returns the expected pear help menu.

If I return to the init.pp file, and uncomment `include pear` and re-run `puppet /etc/puppet/modules/webserver/manifests/init.pp`, the same error appears.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by upgrading to Puppet 2.27, then using puppet-pear module.

https://rubygems.org/gems/puppet/versions/2.7.23

https://github.com/rafaelfelix/puppet-pear